# Чем заменить Suspend и Resume при работе с потоками?

Tags: delphi, многопоточность, delphi-xe

Есть такой метод в одном стареньком компоненте:

```
procedure TTangentThread.SetActive(Value: Boolean);
begin
 if Value <> FActive then
  begin
   FActive := Value;
   case FActive of
    False:
     begin
      FThread.Suspend;
      if (IsRuntime) and (Assigned(FOnSuspend)) then FOnSuspend(self);
     end;
    True:
     begin
      FThread.Resume;
      if (IsRuntime) and (Assigned(FOnResume)) then FOnResume(self);
     end;
   end;
  end;
end;
```

И он, в общем то, работает, но компилятор говорит, что Suspend и Resume устарели и их лучше не использовать. Как это нынче правильно переписать, не используя "устаревших" методов?

Comment: "Устарели" эти методы только с точки зрения стилей программирования. Так что, если не будете переписывать, ничего особо не потеряете. А "правильно" переписывать - это заменить функции Suspend/Resume на работу с объектами синхронизации: например SyncObjs.TEvent - рабочий поток ждёт, пока не сработает событие, выполняет работу, и снова (в цикле) ждёт следующего срабатывания события... Если при каких-то условиях поток должен скипать работу, ну можно рабочий код поместить в "if".

Comment: @velial не хотите оформить ответом?

Comment: @kami чтобы ответом оформлять надо, наверное, привести пример более правильной работы через события. Было бы у velial для этого желание, думаю он бы сразу в виде ответа написал)

Comment: @Isaev ок. попробую сам. Тем более, что утверждение про устаревание исключительно с точки зрения стиля - не совсем корректно, можно нарваться на неприятности при использовании разделяемых данных. К сожалению, лучшая статья про многопоточность (была на винграде) почила в бозе. Вместе со старым винградом...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Suspend` и `Resume` на самом деле выполняются операционной системой. Для Windows внутри этих методов вызываются [SuspendThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686345(v=vs.85).aspx) и [ResumeThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685086(v=vs.85).aspx)

Функции "живее всех живых", но... использовать их действительно не стоит. Проблема в том, что они работают с потоком "здесь и сейчас". То есть - если команда `Suspend` застала поток посередине выполнения оператора (например - присвоения строки) то именно в этой точке поток заснет.

Естественно, такая "произвольность" не способствует качественному выполнению приложения, особенно - если дополнительный и основной поток работают над разделяемыми (совместными) данными. Например, дополнительный поток начал изменять массив (строку, список и т.п.), в это время его "заснули", основной поток обнулил массив и разбудил дополнительный. В дополнительном потоке штатная проверка размерности уже пройдена, поэтому он не узнает о том, что того элемента, над которым поток пытается работать, уже нет. В результате - гарантированная порча памяти со всеми вытекающими последствиями.

Именно поэтому нужно использовать объекты синхронизации: [`TCriticalSection`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SyncObjs.TCriticalSection), [`TMutex`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SyncObjs.TMutex), [`TEvent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SyncObjs.TEvent), [`TSemaphore`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SyncObjs.TSemaphore), [`TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.SysUtils.TMultiReadExclusiveWriteSynchronizer), которыми ограждается доступ к разделяемым ресурсам и / или посылаются "правильные", в "нужные моменты времени" управляющие сигналы. Альтернатива (не кросс-платоформенная) - использовать [механизм сообщений](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644928(v=vs.85).aspx).

В качестве примера: дополнительный поток по команде должен выполнить какую-то работу и ожидать новую команду:

```
uses
  System.SyncObjs;
type
  TmyThread = class(TThread)
  private
    FEvent: TEvent; // "синхронизатор"

    procedure DoWork; // в этом методе будет выполняться полезная работа
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure StartSingleWork; // этот метод вызывается "извне"
  end;

{ TmyThread }

constructor TmyThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FEvent := TEvent.Create; // создаем сигнальное событие
end;

procedure TmyThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
    begin
      FEvent.WaitFor; // ожидаем, пока взведут событие
      FEvent.ResetEvent; // сбрасываем событие,чтобы
      // опять войти в ожидание на WaitFor

      if not Terminated then // и если поток не уничтожают
        DoWork; // делаем свое дело.
    end;
end;

procedure TmyThread.StartSingleWork;
begin
  // кто-то извне хочет, чтобы поток выполнил свою работу
  FEvent.SetEvent; // выводим поток из спячки.
  // поток будет выведен из ожидания в WaitFor, 
  // выполнит полезную работу и опять заснет.
end;

procedure TmyThread.DoWork;
begin
  // здесь выполняется какая-то полезная работа
  // в контексте нашего дополнительного потока.
end;

destructor TmyThread.Destroy;
begin
  Terminate; // начинаем уничтожение

  FEvent.SetEvent; // выводим поток из спячки
  while not Finished do // ждем, пока он завершится
    Sleep(0);
  FreeAndNil(FEvent); // и уничтожаем содержимое потока.

  inherited;
end;
```

В дополнение: на мой взгляд, лучшая из статей про многопоточность в Delphi (и не только). К сожалению - [только в web.archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170517225050/http://forum.vingrad.ru:80/topic-60076.html)...

Upd. Старый форум Винграда ожил, [прямая ссылка на статью](http://forum.vingrad.ru/forum/topic-60076.html)

Answer (score 1):

Эти методы не "устарели", дело здесь в другом. Насколько я знаю, они используются отладчиком для управления потоками во время отладки. И если эти методы используются в вашем приложении, можно нарваться на "непонятные глюки" во время отладки. Или вот что будет с вашим приложением, если вы приостановите поток в то время когда он занял какой-нибудь критически важный системный объект? По-хорошему, приостанавливать работу потока нельзя, можно "попросить" его остановиться в удобный для него момент. Для этого надо использовать объекты синхронизации, например `TEvent`. Поток в своем цикле проверяет состояние этого объекта синхронизации и либо ждет пока можно будет работать, либо работает.

Если вам нужно только один раз запустить поток в нужный момент, то можно использовать метод `Start`.

Если вам очень хочется избавиться от предупреждений компилятора, можно использовать свойство `Suspended` (`Suspended := False;` или `Suspended := True;`) вместо `Suspend` и `Resume`. Это уберет предупреждения компилятора, но не избавит от возможных проблем.

Comment: Вот интересно, почему человек, который поставил минус за ответ, поленился написать комментарий? Что не так с моим ответом?

Comment: Потому что вовсе не из-за отладчика их признали устаревшими. Они попросту не позволяют обеспечивать синхронизацию с достаточной надежностью.